# Comparing Two parts of two String in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, regex, range

I have  columns in my db called range which stores values like this "2500-3000", and i am receiving and input from the client in the same format. What i want to do is search through my db to find the range in which the clients input will fall. what i need is an sql query that could effectively compare those ranges.

Comment: have you tried any thing so far !!

Comment: You should consider normalizing your database and storing the range in two separate columns.

Comment: Looks like an XY-problem. I think the design of the database is flawed. Instead of storing the range specifications as strings there should be two numeric fields describing the range boundaries. The client input then can be parsed also into two numbers, for which the comparison of overlapping or containing ranges is trivial.

Comment: This is a horrifying way to save data

Answer (score -2):

Use BETWEEN operator

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name BETWEEN 2500 AND 3000.
```

Comment: This neither considers user input nor the question-specific range storage.